# Code Coverage issues when deploying change set

Tags: apex, trigger, code-coverage

I'm attempting to deploy a change set from my Sandbox to the production environment. The change set includes 1 Custom Object, several dozen custom fields, a controller (Apex class), and a static resource (an image file). When deploying the inbound change set, I get code coverage errors relating to 2 triggers. There are no triggers in my change set, so I'm confused as to why I'm getting these errors on this specific operation.

The only reason I could see this happening is if the triggers already on the live server, independent of this change set, are written so that they lack the appropriate code coverage. However, wouldn't this error have popped up when the triggers were committed?

I'm only in charge of a small portion of our SalesForce instance, so I lack the scope of responsibilities necessary to start messing with these unrelated triggers. Is there anything I can do to get my change set deployed with this being the case?

Comment: Even if your changeset is not having any trigger, when you deploy any changeset from sandbox to production containing apex code, it would run all test classes by default. Issue with trigger's test class failure could be due to several reasons like badly written test class. May be you should ask responsible person to update test classes. Validation rules can be also responsible for failure of triggers mostly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no triggers in your change set, but is there test code for the apex controller? Salesforce requires 75% cumulative code coverage, which includes Apex controllers, so if the code coverage in your production org is just above 75% and your controller is untested it could drag the total code coverage down to below the threshold. It's also possible that the total is already below 75% in your production environment, possibly caused by an admin changing workflow rules, validation rules, or process builder processes without checking tests.

Comment: This sort of thing has happened to me before. It's a real pain in the neck! I also had an issue once when Salesforce changed the way that they calculated test coverage. I didn't see anything related to this in the latest release notes, but once bitten....

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of what Apex code you are deploying, if you are deploying any Apex code to production, tests will need to run.  Given the defaults, you require:

- At least 75% code coverage throughout all Apex code. (For details on how this is calculated, look [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_code_coverage_intro.htm).
- Greater than 0% code coverage on all triggers.

Now, if you are in a pinch and you need to deploy quickly, you can opt to "Run Selected Tests".  If you do so, you will only need test coverage of the classes/triggers you are deploying.  However, each *individual* test will require 75% code coverage.  Documentation [here](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_deployment_run_subset_of_tests.htm).

However, unless there are special circumstances, I would strongly recommend against this.  If items you are deploying interact with other code in the org, skipping the tests for that code could cause you to overlook dangerous errors you may be introducing into the codebase.

Answer (score 0):

So I wasted almost an entire day on this, but seems like I figured it out. Our salesforce has Apex classes that have 0% code coverage and that's bringing our percentage down and not letting me deploy code that's >90% coverage. Here's the trick: When deploying, select **Run specified tests** and put a comma delimited list of your test class names in your change set. This way you're able to deploy your changeset with good test coverage!

Comment: This is really the same as the answer provided by SFDC Neuf here when the question was first posted.